might as well + have + pp construction (what is the meaning and what's the function of 'as well' here?)

might as well + have + pp construction

What's the meaning of this construction and 'as well'?
I think there is 'might (just) as well', so 'as well' has its own meaning.
The below is just an example. You can give me any examples.
Thank you in advance.

I might as well go home.


I might as well have gone home.


The couple might as well have been strangers.


They might as well have put a gun to her head.


https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/might%2Fmay%20as%20well It's in the dictionary.

Inserting 'just' merely intensifies the sentiment.

Google sense 2 for as well
says

with equal reason or an equally good result "I may as well have a look"


I might as well go home.

means going home will give an equally good outcome as otherwise (like remaining here and so on).

The couple might as well have been strangers.

means the way they live their lives is no different from
how two strangers would do.

Thx. Seowjooheng. "The couple might as well have been strangers." is looking to mean roughly There is a reasonable possibility that the couple were strangers. The last sentence in you answer looks weird.

@gomadeng, To have the possibility interpretation you mentioned, we say
The couple might have been strangers.
